# TimeLine Design for android

Tags: android, timeline

i want to create a timeline that looks like [**this one**](http://timeline.knightlab.com) or [**this one**](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/) with android

who can gives me an idea on how to do or à tutorial please

thank you

Comment: Did you manage to implement the timeline?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a charting library to get a lot of the work done easy, and customise where you need...or develop what you want from first principles to have ultimate control (will be a bit of hard work).

Try using aChartEngine (https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/), perhaps its TimeChart will get you going.